# Why is my envsubst command just inserting blank strings?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, envsubst

I'm trying to run the command `envsubst < myfile` to replace environment variables but instead of being replaced with their values, they are being replaced with blank strings.

Here's my example command (split onto separate lines for clarity):

```
SIGNOFF="Goodbye"
&&
printf "\nOkay, \$SIGNOFF has been set to \"$SIGNOFF\"\n\nOriginal contents:\n\n"
&&
cat test.conf
&&
printf "\n\nContents after envsubst < test.conf\n\n"
&&
envsubst < test.conf | cat
&&
printf "\n\n"
```

Here are my results:

```
$ SIGNOFF="Goodbye" && printf "\nOkay, \$SIGNOFF has been set to \"$SIGNOFF\"\n\nOriginal contents:\n\n" && cat test.conf && printf "\n\nContents after envsubst < test.conf\n\n" && envsubst < test.conf | cat && printf "\n\n"

Okay, $SIGNOFF has been set to "Goodbye"

Original contents:

Hello world, let's change the variable in the quotes below to say Goodbye!
"$SIGNOFF" (it certainly shouldn't just be blank!)

Contents after envsubst < test.conf

Hello world, let's change the variable in the quotes below to say Goodbye!
"" (it certainly shouldn't just be blank!)

$
```

I'm clearly doing something obvious wrong, I just have a silly suspicion it's one of those things that is so obvious that I must be overly complicating my own google searches in trying to find an answer

Comment: `| cat` that's a useless cat.

Comment: Huh... is it?  My real world code is doing a `> otherfile` so I just figured I'd have to pipe it to cat instead =D
Ah well, I know now :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The variable is not exported, so it's not visible to any command. Export it.

```
SIGNOFF="Goodbye"
export SIGNOFF
envsubst < file
```

Comment: Excellent, had to be something obvious like that didn't it! =D
Right then, so I'd better have a think, because my true environment is inside a docker which is bringing in this variable from a .env file.  I wonder if that same .env file can have the export keyword stuck in there too, will give it a go :)

Comment: Thank you for the incredibly fast reply by the way, I'll select as answer the moment when it allows me to =D

Comment: You don't need to put `export` in your `.env`; use `set -a` to enable auto-export before sourcing it, and `set +a` to turn that back off when no longer needed (environment variables use the same limited pool of space that's also used for command-line arguments, so you don't want to export shell variables that don't need to be in the environment, or else you'll be reducing the maximum allowed command-line length unnecessarily).